# How to reproject raster image from WGS84/Pseudo-Mercator to ECEF to ENU in python?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, openstreetmap, wgs84

I am new to GIS and I am writing a program that should work with a cartesian coordinate system, ENU. Therefore my plan is convert all point coordinates from WGS84/Pseudo-Mercator to ECEF and then to ENU.

I can get an OSM map in WGS84/Pseudo-Mercator as geotiff via an API.

How can I reproject the raster map image from WGS84/Pseudo-Mercator to ECEF and then to ENU using python?

Or can I neglect the error on a square map of 50kmˆ2 and avoid reprojecting the raster image.

Comment: EPSG:3857 is a terrible ProjCRS to do analysis in. You don't need to convert to ECEF to reproject to another ProjCRS that would be better. Does the raster actually have elevations? If not, no need to use ENU.

Comment: The map raster itself has no elevation data but I want to put several other raster images on top of the map which give me a DEM.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `rioxarray`.

An example of reprojecting a raster is [here](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/reproject.html).

ECEF - https://epsg.io/4978

```py
import rioxarray

rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio("path_to_raster.tif")
crs = "EPSG:4978" # this depends on the exact projection you want to use
projected = rds.rio.reproject(crs)
projected.rio.to_raster("path_to_enu_raster.tif")
```

Comment: When I run the code on my .tif file I get a white raster as my output. Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What version of GDAL are you using? `rio --gdal-version`

Comment: I have GDAL version 2.4.3, on a macOS Catalina

Comment: How did you install?

Comment: brew install gdal

Comment: Are you able to share the input file?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/opb7bxmezjqniah/berlin.tif

Comment: I see the same result with GDAL 3.0.2. I am wondering if this is a bug in GDAL.

Comment: I have fixed my problem by trying other EPSG codes and the osgeo package. These work for germany "EPSG:4839", "EPSG:3068", "EPSG:25833" and this code:

from osgeo import gdal

filename = "berlin.tif"
input_raster = gdal.Open(filename)
for epsg in ["EPSG:4839", "EPSG:3068", "EPSG:25833"]:
    gdal.Warp('output_raster' + epsg + '.tif', input_raster, dstSRS=epsg)

Comment: That's a great solution as well 